# Custom recyclerview won't to change attribute

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, styles, attr

I found this code on internet, but my recycler won't change attribute by this code. Any solution?

In XML doing right but programmatically nothing.

```
<com.ScrollRecyclerView
    style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"
    android:id="@+id/drop_down_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"></com.ScrollRecyclerView>


 public class ScrollRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    public ScrollRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScrollRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, R.attr.scrollbarStyle);
    }

    public ScrollRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, R.attr.scrollbarStyle);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a simple Recyclerview subclass with standard constructors. It does not do anything the default Recyclerview does not do.

Comment: How are you using the subclass, directly via XML, or creating your own AttributeSet and instantiating yourself via the constructor?

Comment: I'm using from XML via ID

Comment: R.attr.scrollbarStyle is not a style. It's an attribute that can be changed by a style.

Comment: Same result of R.attr.scrollbarStyle and R.style.scrollbar_shape_style

Answer (score 0):

R.attr.scrollbarStyle is not a style. It's an attribute that can be changed by a style.

If you want your RecyclerView to show a scrollbar set the 
android:scrollbars attribute in XML.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I want to custom scrollbar, by this attribute

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Leanback">
    <item name="@attr/scrollbarStyle">@style/scrollbar_shape_style</item>
</style>

<attr name="scrollbarStyle" format="reference"/>

<style name="scrollbar_shape_style">
    <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarStyle">outsideOverlay</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">false</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_track</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarSize">8dp</item>
</style>
```